# How can I set the JavaFX Slider to format for time?

Tags: java, datetime, javafx, slider, javafx-8

I have created a `Slider` using JavaFX. I`m trying to set it up so that it shows time in minutes.

I have been able to setup the the minutes to range from 0 - 60. My problem is my minutes are showing correctly but my seconds are between 0 - 100.

How can I fix this?

*Here is how I created the slider*

```
 <ScrollPane fx:id="RulerScroll1" hbarPolicy="NEVER" maxHeight="40" minHeight="40" pannable="true" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.hgrow="ALWAYS" GridPane.rowIndex="2">    
     <Slider fx:id="Ruler1" majorTickUnit="10" maxHeight="35" min="0" minHeight="35" minorTickCount="4" showTickLabels="true" showTickMarks="true" snapToPixel="true" />  
 </ScrollPane>
```

How can I format the values it gives me so that they can appear as minutes and seconds?

Comment: could you provide us your code? Right now it's impossible to help you.

Comment: I have added the code i used to create the slider. How can i format the number i read in so that it appears as minutes and seconds i.e 1.58 instead of 1.70. The seconds should only count up to 60

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [`StringConverter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/util/StringConverter.html) to display the value of the `Slider` on another control, and also you can use this converter for the [`labelFormatterProperty`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/Slider.html#labelFormatterProperty) of the `Slider`.

**In the Example**

[image]

It sets the range of the `Slider` from 0-3600 and shows the ticks for every 15 minutes in "15:00" format. The value of the `Slider` is displayed on a `Text` control for every second in the same format.

```
public class SliderTime extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            HBox root = new HBox();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);

            Slider sl = new Slider(0, 3600, 20);
            sl.setMajorTickUnit(450);
            sl.setShowTickLabels(true);
            StringConverter<Double> stringConverter = new StringConverter<>() {

                @Override
                public String toString(Double object) {
                    long seconds = object.longValue();
                    long minutes = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMinutes(seconds);
                    long remainingseconds = seconds - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(minutes);
                    return String.format("%02d", minutes) + ":" + String.format("%02d", remainingseconds);
                }

                @Override
                public Double fromString(String string) {
                    return null;
                }
            };

            sl.setLabelFormatter(stringConverter);

            Text text = new Text();

            sl.valueProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) ->
                    text.setText(stringConverter.toString(newValue.doubleValue())));

            root.getChildren().addAll(sl, text);

            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```