# Make a Slider control with multiple nodes in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, slider, javafx-8

I want to make a Slider(bar) control with multiple nodes.

The idea is be able to set intervals of time using them.

For example:

```
                      13:00 pm        4:00 pm
10:00 am ----------------[]------------[]-------------------- 11:00 pm
                   A             B                    C
```

- A = 10:00 am - 13:00 pm
- B = 13:00 am - 4:00 pm
- C = 4:00 am - 11:00 pm

But i just notice that i can't add more nodes to the control. There's any way to do that? Or an alternative solution?

Edit:

In the example are just two nodes, but it can be multiple nodes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If you want to pick ranges,** and you are using JavaFX8, then you could use [RangeSlider](http://controlsfx.bitbucket.org/org/controlsfx/control/RangeSlider.html) from [ControlsFX](http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/).

> The RangeSlider control is simply a JavaFX Slider control with support
>   for two 'thumbs', rather than one. A thumb is the non-technical name
>   for the draggable area inside the Slider / RangeSlider that allows for
>   a value to be set.

It is absolutely what you need, it works as a simple slider but you have a low value and a high value.

**On how to configure the `Slider` to display time values**, a litte hint can be this question:

[How can I set the JavaFX Slider to format for time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37517949/how-can-i-set-the-javafx-slider-to-format-for-time/37519384#37519384)

I don't really see the usecase where more than two thumbs are needed, and I doubt that a complete solution exists, therefore in this case I guess you have to implement your own control. The source of RangeSlider is open, so if you decide to go in this direction I would recommend to firstly check out that.

Comment: Sadly on java 11+ rangeslider is not working in scene builder

Comment: definitely see [this bug](https://github.com/controlsfx/controlsfx/issues/1073) before considering using RangeSlider in a modularized project.